# Why are the gems not findable by 'gem list local' even though the gem folder is full of installed gems?

Tags: windows, ruby, rubygems

When I type:

```
gem env
```

on my Windows system, it produces this info:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - C:/Users/pb/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

When I go to the GEM path:

```
C:\Ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems
```

I see many gem folders with all of the installed gems. But when I type

```
gem list local
```

I get an empty listing:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
```

Why are the gems not findable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but i think the command is

> gem list --local

Answer (score 0):

`gem list local` tells RubyGems to list all gems whose name starts with the string `local`. (See `gem help list` for details.) Do you have any gems with that name installed? Otherwise, it's not really surprising that the list is empty.